# Pandas wrtie to excel not a zip file error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, excel

I had written a function to save a `DataFrame` as a new sheet in an existing Excel file.

```
def saveToExcel(data, excelFile, sheetName):

    book = load_workbook(excelFile)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excelFile, engine = 'openpyxl') 
    writer.book = book

    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

    data.to_excel(writer, index  = False, sheet_name = sheetName, float_format='%.2f')

    writer.save()
```

where `data` is a `DataFrame`, `excelFile` is the `FilePath` and `sheetName` is the name of the sheet.

I get an error that `File is not a zip file` when I try to load the workbook.

This function worked earlier.

**Edit 1**

The file is corrupted. It happens because of the error `can't set attribute` for the code

```
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Your Excel file may be corrupted.

Comment: @BigBen file was corrupted. I have edited the post. Now there is a different error.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that line?

Comment: Now that I have looked at it again, I am not sure. I removed the line and the code works. But I get warnings assigning to `writer.book` and `writer.save` is not part of public API and may not work in the future.

Comment: You should use `writer` as a context manager. See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html).